# как сверстать мобильную версию шапки сайта?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Есть необходимость создать адаптивную шапку сайта с кнопкой гамбургером. В готовых решениях запуталась. Помогите, пожалуйста. Код ниже

```css
.header {
  position: fixed;
  align-content: center;
  left: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 5;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95) none repeat scroll 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.4);
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.header .container {
  width: 1200px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.container .row {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  min-height: 1px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.logotype {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 99px;
  padding-top: 7px;
}

.navigation {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

#nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.main-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: #333;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  list-style: none;
}

.searching {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.main-menu>li>a {
  color: #333;
  display: block;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  line-height: 35px;
  padding: 28px 17px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: medium none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.main-menu>li:hover>a,
.main-menu>li a.active {
  color: #cc3333;
}

.main-menu>li:hover {
  background: #ccc none repeat scroll 0 0;
}

.input-box {
  position: relative;
}

.input-box input {
  background: transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #999;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 45px;
  outline: medium none;
  padding: 0 60px 0 15px;
}

.src-btn {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: medium none;
  color: #999;
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 7px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: visible;
}

.src-btn img {
  width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="logotype">
        <img src="images/stiker.png">
      </div>
      <div class="navigation">
        <nav id="nav-menu">
          <ul class="main-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Поставщики</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Услуги</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Документы</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <a class="toggle-nav" href="#">&#9776;</a>
      <div class="searching">
        <form action="#">
          <div class="input-box">
            <input class="single-input" placeholder="Search" type="text">
            <button class="src-btn">
              <a href="https://icons8.com">
                <img src="https://png.icons8.com/ios-glyphs/50/666666/search.png" />
              </a>
          </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2):

В header добавил блок (бургер).

В CSS через `@media` стили для телефонов размеры сами подстроите под себя, сколько Вам надо.

```js
$('.burger').click(function(){
 $('.phone-hide').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.header {
  position: fixed;
  align-content: center;
  left: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 5;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95) none repeat scroll 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.4);
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.header .container {
  width: 1200px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.container .row {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  min-height: 1px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.logotype {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 99px;
  padding-top: 7px;
}

.navigation {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

#nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.main-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: #333;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  list-style: none;
}

.searching {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.main-menu>li>a {
  color: #333;
  display: block;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  line-height: 35px;
  padding: 28px 17px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: medium none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.main-menu>li:hover>a,
.main-menu>li a.active {
  color: #cc3333;
}

.main-menu>li:hover {
  background: #ccc none repeat scroll 0 0;
}

.input-box {
  position: relative;
}

.input-box input {
  background: transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #999;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 45px;
  outline: medium none;
  padding: 0 60px 0 15px;
}

.src-btn {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: medium none;
  color: #999;
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 7px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: visible;
}

.src-btn img {
  width: 25px;
}
.burger {
  display: none;
}


@media(max-width:767px) {
  header {
    padding: 20px 0;
  }
 .phone-hide {
   display: none;
  
 }
 .burger {
  display: inline-block;
   margin-left: 20px
}
.logotype, .navigation {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.main-menu {
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.main-menu li {
  display: block;
}
.main-menu>li>a {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header">
  <span class="burger">&#9776;</span>
  <div class="container phone-hide">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="logotype">
        <img src="images/stiker.png">
      </div>
      <div class="navigation">
        <nav id="nav-menu">
          <ul class="main-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Поставщики</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Услуги</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Документы</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      
      <div class="searching">
        <form action="#">
          <div class="input-box">
            <input class="single-input" placeholder="Search" type="text">
            <button class="src-btn">
              <a href="https://icons8.com">
                <img src="https://png.icons8.com/ios-glyphs/50/666666/search.png" />
              </a>
          </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/288023)

Comment: Так нормально? Я тут просто впервые (